# Do "accountability partners" increase the chance of achieving personal commitments?

Tags: productivity, lifestyle

An [accountability partner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accountability_partner) is:

> a person who coaches another person in terms of helping the other person keep a commitment.

[Daily Seven](http://www.daily-seven.com) is an example of a site that offers an accountability partner service - ringing you at set times to remind you to stay on task.

> Involving a dispassionate third party in your habit formation gets you better results.

Does anybody know of any scientific studies which show that using accountability partners can effectively help someone to to build a habit or do something? (I'm particularly interested in studies that show that using strangers as accountability partners can do this.)